# Improve the performance of a query on a view which references external tables

Tags: sql, azure, sql-order-by, azure-sql-database

I have a view which looks like this:

```
CREATE VIEW My_View AS
SELECT * FROM My_Table UNION
SELECT * FROM My_External_Table
```

What I have found is that performance is very slow when ordering the data which I need to do for pagination. For example the following query takes almost 2 minutes despite only returning 20 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM My_View 
ORDER BY My_Column
OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

In contrast the following (useless) query takes less than 2 seconds:

```
SELECT * FROM My_View 
ORDER BY GETDATE()
OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

I cannot add indexes to the view as it is not SCHEMABOUND and I cannot make it SCHEMABOUND as it references an external table.

Is there any way I can improve the performance of the query or otherwise get the desired result. All the databases involved are AzureSQL.

Answer (score 1):

If all items are unique in `My_table` and `My_external_table` using `OUTER UNION` would help you to improve the performance.

And adding an index to table would help to run your query faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really get around the `order by` so I don't think there is anything you can do.

I'm a bit surprised the `order by getdate()` works, because ordering by a constant does not usually work.  I imagine it is equivalent to `order by (select null)` and no ordering takes place.

My recommendation?  You probably need to replicate the external table on the local system and have a process to create a new local table.  That sounds complicated, but you may be able to do it using a [materialized view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/materialized-view).  However this works with the "external" table depends on what you mean by "external".

Note that you will also want an index on `my_column` to avoid the sort.